# What are differences of ROS Desktop vs Base?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, ros-indigo, jetson-tk1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm installing ROS Indigo on Jetson TK1 and it's fast enough for RVIZ so I was wanting to install the desktop version but only base is available.

How can I get a list of the packages in Desktop so that I can install them manually? This is all on Ubuntu 14.04 "Trusty" on ARM Jetson TK1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230973/what-are-differences-of-ros-desktop-vs-base?/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably can't install the desktop metapackage on ARM because not all of the packages in it build for ARM.

The full list of which packages are currently available on ARM and which aren't is on the [ARM build status page](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_arm.html)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-05-02**:
Hi Mr. @ahendrix . I wan to install ros on my jetson tx1(ubuntu 16.04). but i dont know which  to install. ros base or ros desktop. please help me this situation

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-05-02**:
All of the packages installed by base are also installed by desktop. Desktop also includes GUI (graphical user interface) packages that are only useful if you have a monitor attached to your TX1.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-05-02**:
I would start with base, and if you find that you need the additional GUI packages, you can install individual packages or the desktop variant later.

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-05-03**:
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The contents of all distribution metapackages is documented in [REP-142](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0142.html):

```
 - ros_base:
    extends: [ros_core]
    packages: [actionlib, angles, bond_core, class_loader,
               dynamic_reconfigure, nodelet_core,
               pluginlib]
```

and:

```
 - desktop:
     extends: [robot, viz]
    packages: [common_tutorials, geometry_tutorials, ros_tutorials,
               roslint, urdf_tutorials, visualization_tutorials]
- desktop_full:
    extends: [desktop, perception, simulators]
```

> How can I get a list of the packages in Desktop so that I can install them manually?

You can use the [rosinstall_generator](http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall_generator) to generate a `.rosinstall` file for you. That would include the necessary information.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-04-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2